# Use Socks5 proxies with Chrome Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, socks

```
        private static ChromeOptions proxy_socks()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write("Enter your proxy: ");
            string proxy_string = Console.ReadLine();
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            var proxy = new Proxy();
            proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
            proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
            proxy.SocksProxy = proxy_string;
            options.Proxy = proxy;
            options.AddArgument("ignore-cretificate-errors");
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
            options.AddArgument("--proxy-server=socks5://" + proxy_string);
            return options;
        }
```

When the program executes this line:

```
ChromeOptions proxy = proxy_socks();
IWebDriver vpn = new ChromeDriver(, proxy);
```

It keeps saying the same errors:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : 'invalid argument: entry 0 of 'firstMatch' is invalid
from invalid argument: cannot parse capability: proxy
from invalid argument: Specifying 'socksProxy' requires an integer for 'socksVersion''
```

**So how can I use socks proxies in Chrome Selenium in C# ?**

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, what is entered string as ```proxy_string ``` variable?

Comment: for exemple 106.54.79.19:1080, an usual socks5 proxy

Comment: everything in your code is ok, did you pass a valid driver service to ChromeDriver ?

Comment: @WillMiles you should use "ignore-certificate-errors" and not "ignore-cretificate-errors"
Did you find a solution for that problem tho ?